# meaning of "following" in a context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Patients are held for observation **following** a medical procedure.

I am having trouble figuring out which event comes first. Does observation happen before medical procedure or medical procedure comes before observation?

Comment: The observation happens afterwards. _Following_ in this case means simply _after_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentence

> Patients are held for observation **following** *a medical procedure*.

The *medical procedure* happens before, the *observation*

It could be restated as

> **Following** *a medical procedure*, patients are held for observation.
>   *After a medical procedure, patients are held for observation.*

Answer (score 1):

In this context just replace the word "**following**" with the word "**after**" (since "to follow" means "to go after...")

> Patients are held for observation **following** a medical procedure.

And you'll get:

> Patients are held for observation **after** a medical procedure.

And it answers directly your question.